# Descriptive word for someone who is ignorant

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me find a word to describe the following:

Someone who thinks they are versed in some subject but really only has a superficial grasp of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do they *know* that they don't know much about the subject and are just trying bluff or do they really think they know everything when if fact they know very little?

Comment: The obvious word would be ignoramus,  but that might not have exactly the connotations you're looking for. Have you tried a thesaurus yet?

Answer (score 1):

***[Sophomoric](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sophomoric)*** comes to mind:

> intellectually pretentious, overconfident, conceited, etc., but immature

Alternatively, you might consider this person to be a [***pseudo-intellectual***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pseudo-intellectual):

> 1. a person exhibiting intellectual pretensions that have no basis in sound scholarship.
> 2. a person who pretends an interest in intellectual matters for reasons of status.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

***ignorant peacock***

> [The Works of Ralph Waldo Emerson, Volume 1](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SDUCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA121&dq=%22ignorant%20peacock%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2pskVc-eMY_LsAS1toDADg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22ignorant%20peacock%22&f=false): By Ralph Waldo Emerson - 2011
>
> And another, an ex-governor of Illinois, said to me, “If a man knew anything, he would sit in a corner and be modest; but he is such an
>   **ignorant peacock**, that he goes bustling up and down, and hits on extraordinary discoveries.”

Now, surely, 
Descriptive word for someone who is ignorant: **ignoramus**

but that doesn't cover the "pride"